# Squirrelmail admin

Tags: linux, email-server

I am helping in a Primary School with IT and they asked if they could monitor the emails when it needed. Is there any way to be able to log in as an admin or other solution for this?

Hi, and thanks for the comments and scores:)))) It is a wrong question I know. So I have an Ubuntu-Karoshi school Image disk and Yes the user end is Squirrelmail...

So altering a question and hoping not to annoy people. Just a starting from the beginning if I may:

How to find out what sort of email server/service runs on this distribution. I have root access but I am not sure where to look at it. If someone would be able to give some command to find it out I would really appreciate.

And if I can report back the second question would be how to be able to get access ino the system for monitoring. Thanks again for teaching me to ask properly.

Comment: You will need to supply more details. Squirrelmail is just a web-based IMAP client.  You will need to tell us where the IMAP server is, and who has access to it.

Comment: This question needs MUCH more detail. Squirrelmail is like the paper wrapper on a piece of fish you just bought. It doesn't tell you much about what's beneath, until the whole thing starts to smell.

Comment: Thanks for the comments I have altered the original question now if that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no simple solution for this at the IMAP client level. Performing this level of email monitoring for an entire mail domain will not work from Squirrelmail.

Further, having been a sometime user and 10-year administrator of a Squirrelmail install, you probably wouldn't WANT to do this from Squirrelmail.

You need to be able to do this kind of operation using a much better client that is connecting directly to the service that is supporting Squirrelmail. If you're completely convinced that you need to do this from the Squirrelmail interface, perhaps some of these [plugins](http://squirrelmail.org/plugins_category.php?category_id=15) will help you.

Comment: You don't need a plugin to do this.  If you're running dovecot for IMAP / POP3 you can authenticate through a master password (I don't not recommend this, but it's possible). 

http://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/MasterUsers

To tell you the truth you should be running something else than Squirrelmail.

Comment: Aye, and I'm sure there's other solutions as well depending on what back-end it's operating, if the OP knows. He's still kinda mental if he actually wants to do it using Squirrelmail.

Comment: Hi thanks I just discovering this system so sorry for the lack of the info however I am willing to give more with some guide.